# Removing metal p trap from PVC stubout

Tags: plumbing, p-trap

I am replacing a p-trap and am having trouble removing the metal trap arm (?) from the PVC stubout. The metal trap arm is threaded onto the PVC. I tried using pretty full strength to twist/unthread off but it is not budging. Haven’t used full strength yet as I don’t want to crack the PVC stubout. Could this be glued on? Can I heat it (the metal part) and see if that loosens it? I assume I could just cut it off but I’d rather not have to put a new connector on and whatever else comes with that. As you can see the metal is rounded and not threaded so tough to get a good grip on it with hand or wrench.

The metal collar slides a half inch or so away from the wall and exposes the PVC stubout entering the tile wall.

Any advice helpful. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like thread compound was used. You'll either need more force, or a solvent, or some heat.

I'd start by carefully heating the metal part with a heat gun, hair dryer, or boiling water. It may soften things for you. Since you're replacing the part, a pipe wrench is the ticket.

Comment: Thank you. If using a torch, how much leeway do I have before melting the pvc? I’ll start at the opposite end of the pipe and far away, but is the pvc super susceptible to melting?

Comment: You shouldn't hit more than about 150 degrees. If that doesn't do it, more heat probably won't help.

Comment: Thanks. If worst case I need to cut it off before the threads, does the remaining 2” of stub out give me enough to put a new fitting/connector on there?

Comment: I think so. Most joint sockets for 1-1/2" pipe are an inch or less deep.

Comment: Cool. Maybe take the [tour] so you know how to properly show it. "Thanks" comments are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites. :)